# Is it possible to set condition to empty parameter in cerberus?

Tags: python, validation, conditional-statements, cerberus

I want to set conditional validate for `empty` parameter.
For example:

```
schema = {
'param1': {'type': 'string', empty: False, required:True, 'allowed': ['One', 'Two']},
'param2': {'type': 'string', empty: False, required:True}
}
```

I need that `empty` parameter in `param2` determined by the condition:

If `param1` == 'One' =>> `empty` in `param2` = True
else False

I tried like that:
`'param2': {'type': 'string', empty: {'if': {'param1': 'One'}, 'then': True, 'else': False}, required:True}`

But get error: `[{'empty': ['must be of boolean type']}]`

Of course, it because `empty` wait for boolean type.

But if there are some solution for this option?

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you want, but the only interactions between fields that cerberus allows are `excludes` and `dependencies`. You can imitate an if statement such as `if value == "One" then exclude "param2" else require "param2"` like this:

```json
"param1": {
  "allowed": ["One", "Two"],
  "oneof": [
    {
      "allowed": ["One"],  # condition
      "excludes": ["param2"]  # then rule
    },
    {
      "forbidden": ["One"],  # inverse condition
      "dependencies": ["param2"]  # else rule
    }
  ]
}
```

Logically the schema translates to

given: p <- param1 has value of "One", q <- exclude param2, r <- require param2

then: (p and q) xor (not p and r) <=> if p then q else r